# Chart control in visual web developer express 2010 is unavailable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts

I've just rebuilt my PC and have upgraded to visual web developer express 2010. I have imported my projects which use the charting control quite a bit. Unfortunately my projects are failing to run. In design view the control is now showing as "unknown server tag asp:chart". I can see the Chart control in the data tab in the toolbox but it is greyed out.

Does anyone have an idea for how I can fix this?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I found was the Graphics Server .NET that should be downloaded and installed. There is an express editon which should become available when you register the VS Epress Edition. A link is to be send vai mail in order to download Graphics Server .NET.

However: I never got the email, so I'm stuck at this part as wel.

Please look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308769.aspx for more info.